# Can't match word with following \ and all symbols after in my regular expression

Tags: regex

I need match next cases:

```
no word\ on your
no word\on your
no word\
no word
```

ignoring :

```
no word on your
```

My regular expression doesn't cover my needs

```
^.*(?=\bword\b)(?:\\.*|)$
```

To verify results you can use [prepared configuration](https://regex101.com/r/zYE6JB/1).

...Looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your positive lookahead is followed with `\\.*` optional pattern followed with end of string, so the `word` string should either start at the same location as `\` does or at the end of string, which means, your regex will never match any text.

You can use

```js
^.*\bword(?:\\.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t8nuSN/2). There is no need adding another `\b` as `\` after `word` is already a non-word char, and if the optional `\\.*` pattern does not exist, the end of string is already acting as a trailing word boundary for `word`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `word` - a `word`
- `(?:\\.*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching `\` and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.